# Problems with creating regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm working on regex (regexes, actually) that will satisfy my needs. :)

I need to replace given string (named `title`) and return `slug`:

1. Replace one white-space with one underscore in places where are one white-space. If there are more then one white-space, only one white-space should be replaced. It's hard to explain, but I will try to explain with example. `Hi and hello, world!` would be `Hi_and_hello,_world!`, but if there would be, for example, two white-spaces before 'world', it would be `Hi_and_hello,_ world!`,
2. Replace all remaining white-spaces with nothing (`''`),
3. Replace all unwanted characters (white-list: `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and underscore). In other words, if symbol isn't in the white-list, it should be replaced with nothing (`''`),
4. Trim beginning and end from underscores;

The end result should be:

`Hello, world! I'm known as daGrevis. :)`

...to:

`Hello_world_Im_known_as_daGrevis`

All that stuff I need to do in the JavaScript. This is what I got so far:

```
slug = title.replace(/\s+/g, '_');
slug = title.replace(/\s+/g, '');
slug = title.replace(/[^\w0-9a-zA-Z]/g, '');
```

I'm not good with regexies so don't laugh on me. :D Thanks in an advice!

Comment: I don't understand the second rule, what are the remaining white-spaces, you already replace them by the first rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In other words:

1. Replace all consecutive spaces by one underscore
2. Remove all unwanted characters
3. Remove the underscores at the beginning and end

There you go:

```
var slug = title.replace(/\s+/g, '_');
slug = slug.replace(/[^0-9a-z_]/gi, '');
slug = slug.replace(/^_+|_+$/g, "");
```

- `\s+` matches as much consecutive whitespace (space, newline, tab, ..) as possible
- `/g` is a global flag, means: "select every match"
- `/[^a-z0-9_]/gi` means: Anything which is not an alphanumeric character or underscore, case insensitive
- `^` and `$` are markers for the beginning and end of a string.
  `^_+|_+$/g` means: match every underscore at the beginning and end of a string

Don't forget to perform the following replacements on `slug`, instead of `title`. Otherwise, you "forget" your previous replacements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Anyway, [it doesn't work as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/zXKRv). :(

Comment: The last could be replaced with `/[^\w]/` as `\w` is short for `A-Za-z0-9_`.

Comment: @ridgerunner When using `\W`, the `i` flag can also be omitted.

Comment: Close, but this solution erroneously results in more than one underscore in a row for strings such as: `"Hello , , , world!"`

Comment: @ridgerunner Why is it erroneous? I've strictly followed the ruleset as defined at the OP.

Comment: @Rob W - Yes, you are correct. I jumped to the conclusion that the OP would like: `"Hello , , , world!` to become: `"Hello_world"` rather than: `"Hello____world"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

```js
slug = title.replace(/[^\s\w]+/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, '_').replace(/^_|_$/g, '');
```